# Can i use cuda folder from meta-tegra master branch in thud meta-tegra branch?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm attempting to create an image for my NVIDIA jetsons-nano (following [this guide](https://www.konsulko.com/building-a-custom-linux-distribution-for-nvidia-cuda-enabled-embedded-devices/)).

When building the very basic image, the build terminates with an error saying it cannot find cuda-repo-l4t-10-0-local-10.0.166... and that is because the NVIDIA SDK downloads cuda-repo-l4t-10-0-local-10.0.326... I can see that the meta-tegra thud branch does in fact contain recipes needing the 10.0.166 CUDA version. Meanwhile the master branch contains recipes needing the updated 10.0.326 CUDA that the NVIDIA SDK provides.

So my question is this: can I just copy the cuda recipes folder from master branch (meta-tegra/recipes-devtools/cuda) and replace the cuda recipe folder in the used meta-tegra layer in my build? Or can I download the CUDA 10.0.166 from the SDK instead somehow?

[SOLVED]As a side question, the build complains that is cannot find "cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-0-local-10.0.326-410.108_10.0-1_amd64.deb"... which is because I downloaded from the NVIDIA SDK on a ubuntu 16.04 system and not 18.04.. What can I do about this? I can see that there is recipe for both 18.04 and 16.04, but it runs through both?

As another side question, the meta-tegra layer of the thud branch does not have the MACHINE conf for jetson-nano. But I assume these configs are somewhat independent, so I took the jetson-nano config file from the master branch aswell. This is fine right?

Answer (score 0):

For the cuda SDK, you need to do something like this in local.conf:

CUDA_BINARIES_NATIVE = "cuda-binaries-ubuntu1604-native"

edit: I also want to add that you may have less difficulty gett Warrior to work with the latest SDK rather than backing off to Thud.

Comment: See https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra/wiki/L4T-R32.2.1-Notes for information about this package.

Comment: I was literally just about to delete that side question as I figured out I had to write that line in the local.conf file, but thank you!

I'm a bit hesitant to attempt on the Warrior branch as the problem about CUDA only supporting gcc 7 and not gcc 8 is scaring me a bit. I don't really understand how to add the external toolchain yet

Comment: Add the meta-linaro layer and put this in your local.conf

```GCCVERSION = "linaro-7.2"

SDKGCCVERSION = "linaro-7.2"```